# How to add heading or text before input/output in gradio?

Tags: machine-learning, deployment, mnist, gradio

I did a machine learning project on MNIST and deployed that on gradio. Any user won't understand what he should input to use the model. So I want to add a heading or description on gradio live website so that anyone can understand.

I tried with gradio block, gradio.markdown but it's not working on Google colab

Answer (score 1):

The base gradio ["Interface"](https://www.gradio.app/docs/interface) class has parameters (title, description & article) that take strings and are rendered as helpful text for the app.  These are the simplest ways to provide some context and instruction.

For example:

```
title = "Awesome ML App"
desc = "This is an awesome ML App.  I'm really excited to show you"
long_desc = "Let me tell you ALL about this awesome ML App"
iface = gr.Interface(fn=classify_image, inputs=image, outputs=label, theme=gr.themes.Glass(), 
                examples=[example1, ref_example, example2], title=title, 
                description=desc, article=long_desc)
```